# Why Image Assest is not displayed

Tags: android-studio, flutter

I want to display an image asset in flutter using Android Studio ,
but the it's not showing up in the app ,even though it takes space

I have used the flutter inspector when i choose the image it shows me the as white square where the image should be .
I have already added the asset in pubsec.yaml

Image assest code

```
class CarsImage extends StatelessWidget{

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    AssetImage carAsset = AssetImage('ímages/buga.png');

    Image im = Image(image: carAsset,height: 250.0,width: 250.0,);


    return im;
  }
}



class Home extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // TODO: implement build
    return CarsImage()
    ;
  }
```

pubsec.yaml

```
flutter:

  # The following line ensures that the Material Icons font is
  # included with your application, so that you can use the icons in
  # the material Icons class.
  uses-material-design: true

  # To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:
  assets:
    - images/
```

I expect the image to show up .

Comment: It's only a typo in your case: should be `'images/buga.png` instead of `'ímages/buga.png'`. See the i with accent.

Answer (score 3):

If you added images inside folder named "assets" in your project and inside that you have created folder named "images", then try with defining it in your `pubspec.yaml` as per below:

```
    - assets/images/buga.png
```

After that, you can use image from asset as per below:

```
Image.asset('assets/images/buga.png')
```

Answer (score 1):

The "i" in your path seems weird if you look closely, so i change it to normal "i". Perhaps it's because of this.

Also, you don't have two create two image assets. One will do. And enclose it with a container so you can adjust it wherever your like.

Try this:

```
class CarsImage extends StatelessWidget{

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Container(
      //you can make the width/height dynamic
      width: 250.0,
      height: 250.0,
      child: new Image.asset('images/buga.png', height: 250.0, width: 250.0)
    );
  }

}
```